# Creating Ember.Select objects in a loop tied to different models

Tags: ember.js

I need to display several `Ember.Select` widgets in a loop:

```
{{#each foo}}
  {{view Ember.Select
       selectionBinding="App.s1.selected"
       contentBinding="App.s1.content"
  }}
}}
```

The problem is that this will tie all these selects to the same model (`"App.s1"`). How can I tie each `Ember.Select` to a different model?

Ideally, I'd like to define an array of my models and in the loop, tell Ember to use the index "i" of that array, where "i" is the index of the current iteration. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to store all of your sN's (s1, s2, s3, etc) in an array, say `App.contentArray`, and then in your template do

```
{{#each item in App.contentArray}}
     {{view Ember.Select selectionBinding="item.selected" contentBinding="item.content"}}
{{/each}}
```

No need for an `i` index or explicit for loops.

Comment: I don't think this will work since I'm inside an iteration already. With your example, I will get n SELECTs times the number of elements in the outer loop (elements in foo).

Comment: So, what exactly do you want? You want to display a list of models, and for each displayed model, you want to have an Ember.Select that does... what?